# p-value, sample statistics

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, sampling

How would one prove that

$\text{Prob}(Z<z_{calc})$ is the $p$-value where $z_{calc}$ is the sample statistics $\sqrt(n)(\bar{x}-\mu_0)/\sigma$. Here, $p$-value is the probability of observing data which are similar to, or more extreme if $H_0$ happens to be true.

Comment: It is a definition...

Comment: I do not follow. What is a definition of what? Thank you

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(Z < Z_{calc}) = p.value$ is by definition the p.value of one sided test with $Z$ statistics. There is nothing to prove.